# autocomplete = "off" ignored in IE?

Tags: asp.net, forms, internet-explorer, checkbox, autocomplete

I have a form with checkboxes, with their 'checked' value being populated from code behind in a database.

Imagine, if I have checkboxes 1,2 and 3 all set to checked in the database. I load the page, uncheck checkbox 3 and then commit the changes to the database. Now in my database, checkboxes 1 and 2 are checked and 3 is unchecked. I refresh the page, it gets the updated database values and the checkboxes have the correct checked values.

This is only working for me in chrome and FF. In IE, even if I uncheck checkbox 3, commit the changes to the database and refresh, it still appears checked. I forced a refresh with ctrl+f5 and it still isn't updating. Adding autocomplete="off" to both the checkboxes and parent form did nothing.

Comment: Which EI version are we talking about here?

Comment: I'm testing in IE 10.

Comment: Are you using a compatibility mode setting in IE, or native IE 10 settings ?

Comment: I'm using IE 10 settings straight out of the box.

Comment: Is the form data filled in with AJAX?  IE caches AJAX requests and will used the cached version which may be why the data does not change in IE.  Try the update with SQL profiler on to ensure that the DB is indeed being updated when using IE or have fiddler up and running to make sure the post back / data fill is not using a cached version

Comment: That was it. I didn't know AJAX is cached in IE and I've sorted the problem now. I don't think I can award the bounty to a comment, so if you write an answer I'll award the bounty to you :)

Comment: Please check if there is any console.log in any js function, as for me before that caused a hidden problem. The code was also working perfectly on Chr & FF but on IE it wasn't work as expected and no exception appears in the console. you should configure something in the options in order for IE to catch all errors!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is already answered in comments but no relevant answer is provided in Answers. I am trying to answer it here so that it will be useful for all others users facing same issue.

The solution can be :

Consecutive ajax call with no change in request are often considered as cached by some browsers and this issue is particularly reproducible in `IE 10`. The response for request is `HTTP 304 Not Modified` and request doesn't hit the database. The solution is to use `ajaxSetup` to set `cache` to `false` like :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
```

NOTE: This will set cache false for all ajax calls in the session.

**OR**

Using `cache: false` in particular ajax calls, if you don't want to disable cache for all ajax calls.

```
$.ajax({
         ...
         cache: false,
         ...
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be better to use javascript `node.autocomplete = 'off'`. Some times it helps.

And don't forget that IE sometimes [really ignored autocomplete](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2013/09/24/internet-explorer-11-changelist-change-log.aspx), for example, IE11 ignores autocomplete=off for input type="password" to `keeps user in control`.